# Subject encoded email (RFC2047). Decodes wrong

Tags: email, go

I'm writing app in Golang. I need to decode email subject.

Original subject:

> Raport z eksportu ogłoszeń nieruchomości

Encoded subject:

```
=?utf-8?B?RG9tLmV1IC0gcmFwb3J0IHogZWtzcG9ydHUgb2fFgm9zemXF?=  =?utf-8?B?hCBuaWVydWNob21vxZtjaQ==?=^M
```

Decoded subject: "Raport z eksportu ogłosze▒  ▒ nieruchomości"

I use github.com/famz/RFC2047 to decode email subjects.

My code is simple:

```
RFC2047.Decode(msg.Header.Get("Subject"))
```

Why, after decoding the subject is broken? Other subjects are correctly decoded. Is this a bad encoded subject?

Comment: Looks like it's splitting an UTF-8 character in half.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Go 1.5, you can use the new functions of the [mime package](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/).

If you're using an older version of Go, you can use [my drop-in replacement](https://github.com/alexcesaro/quotedprintable).

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mime" // When using Go 1.5
    mime "gopkg.in/alexcesaro/quotedprintable.v3" // When using older Go versions
)

func main() {
    s := "=?utf-8?B?RG9tLmV1IC0gcmFwb3J0IHogZWtzcG9ydHUgb2fFgm9zemXF?=  =?utf-8?B?hCBuaWVydWNob21vxZtjaQ==?="
    dec := new(mime.WordDecoder)
    subject, err := dec.DecodeHeader(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(subject)
    // Output:
    // Dom.eu - raport z eksportu ogłoszeń nieruchomości
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That subject is incorrectly encoded.
It was broken into two MIME encoded-words (because the encoded line would be longer than 76 characters), but it was split in the middle of the `ń` character.

If you join the two parts into a single encoded string, you get back the original subject:

```
s := "=?utf-8?B?RG9tLmV1IC0gcmFwb3J0IHogZWtzcG9ydHUgb2fFgm9zemXFhCBuaWVydWNob21vxZtjaQ==?="
fmt.Println(RFC2047.Decode(s))

// Dom.eu - raport z eksportu ogłoszeń nieruchomości
```

Comment: @tomwilde: yes, I mentioned that was why the word was split, albeit incorrectly.

Comment: @tomwilde: oh, and 76chars (78-CRLF) is only the per-line recommendation. You can fold headers accross multiple lines: see 2.3.3 in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt

Answer (score 0):

In free time I wrote this function. The function joins parts of string and return one string.

```
func parseSubject(s string) string {
   patternType := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)=\\?.*?\\?.*?\\?")
   resType := patternType.FindString(s)

   if resType == "" {
      return s
   } else {
      pattern := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)=\\?.*?\\?.*?\\?|\\s+|\\?=")
      res := pattern.ReplaceAllLiteral([]byte(s), []byte(""))

      return resType + string(res) + "?="
   }
}
```